# GRASS r.denoise error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, smoothing

I have installed r.denoise, put mdenoise into QGIS2.18/bin and installed "pip install pyproj".
However when I try to run r.denoise on STRM DEM, a get this error:

`ERROR: Unable to open file <tmp_xyz_5660.xyz> for writing
Removing temporary files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/scripts
/r.denoise.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/scripts
/r.denoise.py", line 166, in main
    grass.run_command('r.out.xyz', input=in_raster,
output=tmp_xyz, separator='space', overwrite=True)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\py
thon\grass\script\core.py", line 410, in run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args,
kwargs)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\py
thon\grass\script\core.py", line 329, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None
['r.out.xyz', '--o', 'input=DEM_sliv_STRM_30x30@PERMANENT',
'separator=space', 'output=tmp_xyz_8292.xyz'] ended with
error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the
(error) output.`

For some time I cant figure out whats the problem and cant find anywhere similar problem.
I am using GRASS GIS 7.2.0 with QGIS 2.18.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: Not a solution, but can you try SAGA GUI (not via Processing Toolbox)?  QGIS 2.18 will come with SAGA 2.1 or later, which has `Mesh Denoise` in `Tools | Grid - Filter`. It is based on Sun et al. (2007).

Comment: I managed it. Thank for Your time and help Mr. Kazuhito!

Comment: Just an update as of QGIS 2.18.14; `Mesh Denoise` tool is now accessible from QGIS Processing Toolbox, `SAGA | Raster filter | Mesh denoise`.